# Entity Framework Inheritance with navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with a code-first approach

[image]

But I get a few errors:

> User: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'User' is not valid. Type 'SoteAccount' of FromRole 'User_SoteAccounts_Target' in AssociationType 'User_SoteAccounts' must exactly match with the type 'AllegroAccount' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.
>   AllegroAccount_Template_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'AllegroAccount_Template_Source' in relationship 'AllegroAccount_Template'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper   bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
>
>   SoteAccount_Template_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'SoteAccount_Template_Source' in relationship 'SoteAccount_Template'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Is it even possible to inherit a class with reference ?

Here are the classes and onModelCreating

```
[Table("AllegroAccounts")]
public class AllegroAccount : ShopAccountBase
{
    public string AllegroLogin { get; set; }
    public string AllegroPassword { get; set; }
    public string AllegoWebApiKey { get; set; }
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }      
}

public class ShopAccountBase : AccountBase
{
    public int TemplateForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TemplateForeignKey")]
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AccountBase
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountBaseId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int UserForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserForeignKey")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public bool DaysCountActive { get; set; }
    public int DaysCount { get; set; }
}

public class Template 
{
    public Template()
    {
        AdditionalServices = new AdditionalServices();
        BasicServices = new BasicServices();
        TemplatePackages = new ObservableCollection<TemplatePackage>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }

    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public TemplateKind? TemplateKind { get; set; }
    public CourierFirm? CourierFirm { get; set; }
    public int Used { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TemplatePackage> TemplatePackages { get; set; }
    public string ExternalNumber { get; set; }
    public string MPKNumber { get; set; }
    public AdditionalServices AdditionalServices { get; set; }
    public BasicServices BasicServices { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public User() 
    {
        DefaultReturnAddress = new Address( );
        DefaultSendingAddress = new Address( );
        PersonInfoSending = new PersonInfo( );
        PersonInfoReturning = new PersonInfo( );
        AdditionalServices = new AdditionalServices( );

        WayBillLabel = new WaybillLabel( );
        Settings = new UserSettings( );
        AllegroAccounts = new ObservableCollection<AllegroAccount>();
        InpostAccounts = new ObservableCollection<InpostAccount>();
        TbaAccounts = new ObservableCollection<TbaAccount>();
        TruckerAccounts = new ObservableCollection<TruckerAccount>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public Address DefaultReturnAddress { get; set; }
    public Address DefaultSendingAddress { get; set; }

    public PersonInfo PersonInfoSending { get; set; }
    public PersonInfo PersonInfoReturning { get; set; }

    public string MPKnumReturn { get; set; }
    public string MPKnumSending { get; set; }

    public AdditionalServices AdditionalServices { get; set; }

    public float MaxLength { get; set; }
    public float MaxWidth { get; set; }
    public float MaxHeight { get; set; }
    public float MaxWeight { get; set; }

    public int FileTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string CollectiveShipmentFilePath { get; set; }

    private PermissionFlags _permissions;

    public PermissionFlags Permissions
    {
        get { return _permissions; }
        set
        {
            if (_permissions.HasFlag(value)) { _permissions &= ~value; }
            else {
                _permissions |= value;
            }
        }
    }

    public TemplatingMethod TemplatingMethod { get; set; }

    public UserSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public WaybillLabel WayBillLabel { get; }

    public ICollection<AllegroAccount> AllegroAccounts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SoteAccount> SoteAccounts { get; set; }

    public ICollection<InpostAccount> InpostAccounts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TruckerAccount> TruckerAccounts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TbaAccount> TbaAccounts { get; set; }

    // this is the right property to use for modifying the collection
    public ICollection<string> AvailableMpksCollection { get; set; }

    // this is computed property for Entity Framework only, because it cannot store a collection of primitive type
    public string AvailableMpksString
    {
        get { return AvailableMpksCollection != null ? string.Join(",", AvailableMpksCollection) : null; }
        set {
            AvailableMpksCollection = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.Split(',').ToList( ) : new List<string>( );
        }
    }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<AllegroAccount>().HasOptional(account => account.Template).WithOptionalDependent();

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<AllegroAccount>(u => u.AllegroAccounts)
            .WithOptional(acc => acc.User)
            .HasForeignKey(acc => acc.UserForeignKey);

modelBuilder.Entity<SoteAccount>().HasOptional(account => account.Template).WithOptionalDependent();

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<SoteAccount>(u => u.SoteAccounts)
            .WithOptional(acc => acc.User)
            .HasForeignKey(acc => acc.UserForeignKey);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible or should I keep it flat and don't inherit it like that? I'm asking because that inheritance would fit nicely with my generic repository model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because you are defining `[ForeignKey]` attributes AND configuring the foreign key in the fluent configuration.

You've defined links between (AllegroAccount and User) and (SoteAccount and User) in the fluent configuration, when your AccountBase already has this defined using the [ForeignKey].

The same thing is most likely true for your Template links - the relationship is defined at the `ShopAccountBase` level by the `[ForeignKey]` attribute - you don't need to redefine it for the inherited classes in the fluent config.

Try removing all of your `modelBuilder` fluent configuration entries - it should still work by inheriting the relationships.